# what is $a^2+9=b^2+16=1+(a+b)^2$ solve for $a,b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

This is for a geometry question, and through a construction arrived at this equation. I could not solve it and after plugging it into wolfram got the correct answer but can anyone show a method for finding a,b

they are $\frac{5}{\sqrt3}$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$ respectively (note since this is a geometry question the lengths of a side cannot be negative so the negative solution sets do not matter)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math.

Comment: Use one equation to express $b $ via $a $, and then substitute it into the other equation.

Comment: have tried to do so

Comment: Please show your work in trying to eliminate one variable or the other.  That will expedite responses that will be helpful to you, at whatever level of studies is appropriate.  You made a start by explaining that by "geometry question" you have intended the unknowns $a,b$ are positive real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from
$$
1+(a+b)^2=b^2+16 \\
\iff a^2+2ab+b^2+1=b^2+16 \\
\iff a^2+2ab-15=0 \\
\iff b= \frac{15-a^2}{2a}
$$
Now substitute in another equality
$$
a^2+9=b^2+16 \\
\iff a^2+9=\left(\frac{15-a^2}{2a}\right)^2+16 \\
\iff a^2+9=\frac{15^2-30a^2+a^4}{4a^2}+16 \\
\iff 3a^4+2a^2-225 = 0 \\
$$
Solve the quadratic for $a^2$, you get
$$
\implies a^2=\frac{25}{3} \implies a=\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}
$$
Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 3):

We have $b^2+2ab-8=0$. Solving this for $a$ and substituting we obtain the following solutions
$$
(a, b)=(3i,-4i),(-3i,4i),(5/\sqrt{3},2/\sqrt{3}),(-5/\sqrt{3},-2/\sqrt{3}).
$$
So the only solution in positive real numbers is $(a, b)=(5/\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: I would have solved your first equation for $a$, which appears only linearly.  Typo maybe?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this way:
$b^2+16=1+(a+b)^2\Rightarrow 15=a(a+2b)$ and $a^2+9=1+(a+b)^2\Rightarrow 8=b(2a+b)$
$\frac{8}{15}=\frac{b(2a+b)}{a(a+2b)}=\frac{x(2+x)}{1+2x}$, where $x=\frac{b}{a}$ (Assuming $a$ and $b$ are positive).
On solving, we get $x=\frac{2}{5}=\frac{b}{a}$.
Thus, $5b=2a$. 
As $a^2+9=b^2+16=(\frac{2a}{5})^2+16$. This gives $a=\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}$. Thus, $b=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. (Considering only positive numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Let
\begin{align} 
a^2+9&=k
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
b^2+16&=k
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
1+(a+b)^2&=k
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}
for some $k>0$.

Then \eqref{3}$-$\eqref{1}$-$\eqref{2} gives

\begin{align}
ab &= 12-\tfrac12\,k
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
a^2b^2 &= (12-\tfrac12\,k)^2
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

On the other hand, from \eqref{1},\eqref{2}
we have

\begin{align}
a^2b^2 &= (k-9)(k-16)
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Combination of \eqref{5} and \eqref{6}
results in equation in $k$:

\begin{align}
k(3k-52)&=0
\tag{7}\label{7}
,
\end{align}

and since $k>0$, we have the only option

\begin{align}
k&=\frac{52}3
\tag{8}\label{8}
.
\end{align}

Then \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} gives possible values of $a$
and $b$:

\begin{align}
a&=\pm \tfrac53\sqrt3
\tag{9}\label{9}
,\\
b&=\pm \tfrac23\sqrt3
\tag{10}\label{10}
.
\end{align}

And since $a,b$ also must be positive, the solution is ready.